# Does netsh add sslcert with a http url still enable ssl?

Tags: wcf, ssl, https, netsh

When hosting a WCF service in a windows service, we can use `netsh http add urlacl url=https://+:1234/xService user=DOMAIN\USER`

Then to add SSL we could do:

```
netsh http add sslcert ipport=0.0.0.0:1234 certhash="xxxxx" appid="{xxxxx}".
```

In the example code here https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms733791(v=vs.110).aspx they seem to use a http address.

Does this make any difference? If you run `netsh http add sslcert` on a port reserved with a http:// address will it still be secured by the certificate, or does it have to be a https address?

Answer (score 0):

It needs to use https and your service should also serve https://...